# Would it be helpful to have a text box to explain flag reasons?

Tags: discussion, flagging

A few times when I have thought about flagging something I kind of wished there was a text box available to explain the reasoning for the flag. I could be tempted to check "other" just to be able to explain what I felt might be wrong (or to explain that there was some uncertainty).

(Part of this may come from personal difficulty with classification--that pixel seems to have a non-zero red value, so can one really say that the image is not red [not *quite* that extreme]--, but it **might** be helpful to the reviewer to have a short text clarifying the reason for the flag even if most people left such blank.)

I am posting this as a discussion question because it seems inappropriate to post it as a feature request on meta.stackoverflow unless it is something that actually would be useful to others.

(I am being lazy in not search M.SO to see if this has been proposed already. I may take a look later.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself needing a custom reason in addition to a canned flag reason you have one of two options.

- You can leave a comment and go with a canned flag reason. This has the advantage of sending it to the 10k flag queue for review in addition to the mod queue.
- You can just send a custom flag.

If your comments cannot be made public in some way, just send a custom flag.

In general I think this covers most cases. We want things to be as *public* as possible here and if you have a reason *why* a question or answer is low quality, or an answer is not an answer. Explain it to the OP. We're all here to learn, and it's helpful to original posters if they are given good feedback. It's also helpful if users are giving this feedback instead of it always being the moderators.

Comment: I take it you mean comment on the possibly offending post and flag the comment. In some rare cases I might like a more private posting because something like "This smells bad in [list of ways]." might be excessively discouraging to a new user when I am not sure about the badness (and have difficulty articulating criticism). Comment and flag comment seems like a decent solution for almost all cases that I would encounter. Thank you. (Usually others beat me to acting on questionable posts anyway.)

Comment: In the case you describe, a custom flag is the best solution.